# shared_instance implementation using C++ and RAII

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-safety, singleton, raii

I created a little `singleton`-like class that gets deleted when there is no reference to it anymore (so its lifetime shall be somewhat predictable). I aimed to make it thread-safe.

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>

template< typename t_type >
struct shared_instance
{
    static std::shared_ptr< t_type > get_shared_instance()
    {
        static std::weak_ptr< t_type > weak;
        static std::mutex mutex;

        auto result = weak.lock();
        if( nullptr == result )
        {
            std::unique_lock< std::mutex > lock{ mutex };

            result = weak.lock();
            if( nullptr != result )
            {
                return result;
            }

            result = std::make_shared< t_type >();
            weak = result;
        }
        return result;
    }
};

template< typename t >
struct context 
{ 
    context() 
    : instance{ shared_instance< t >::get_shared_instance() } 
    { }

private: std::shared_ptr< t > instance;
};
```

I would be glad if you could comment on the implementation itself and how I could tackle non-default-constructible objects (I know of perfect forwarding and variadic templates but I have not found an elegant way to evaluate them lazily).

Comment: Aren't singleton-like things usually a bad idea? What are you aiming for with this, I'm curious.

Comment: yeah they are. however, i need a kind of context-object: using raii to call c-style functions like create (in ctor) and destroy (in dtor). i need to make sure that that context exists as long as i'm using some ressources in that context. the problem is in situations like `context c1{}; /*some code here*/; context c2{};` c2 will tear down the context but it c1 should (braoder scope, calling the create-function mutliple times is not an error from the c-library's point of view). i need a way to make sure that behind the scenes there is only one call to destroy in the dtor of the last instance

Comment: so this is not really a classical singleton that is used to share an instance but rather to make sure that client-code can not accidentally misuse the library code and it remains exception-safe. if there are any other suggestions of how i could accomplish this, let me know, i'd be very happy. by the way: the returned shared_pointer is then hidden in the context-object which acts as kind of a contract meaning that the init/create/.. function was called and that it will be cleaned up extactly once when that context is not referenced anywhere anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Non-Default Constructors:

Adding support for non-default constructible objects in a "lazy" fashion, could be done by adding a factory function of `std::function<std::shared_ptr< t_type >()>`.

```
template< typename t_type >
struct shared_instance
{
    using t_factory = std::function<std::shared_ptr< t_type >()>;

    static t_factory factory; // MUST be set before calling get_shared_instance

    static std::shared_ptr< t_type > get_shared_instance()
    {
        ...


            assert(factory); // or throw, or return empty shared_ptr

            result = factory(); // instead of make_shared

        ...
    }

};

// and define the static member...
template< typename t_type >
typename shared_instance< t_type >::t_factory shared_instance< t_type >::factory;


...

int main()
{
    context<int> c; // not ok... haven't set factory yet!

    // do this before any call to get_shared_instance
    shared_instance<int>::factory = [] () { return std::make_shared<int>(5); }; // store things in the lambda by value, not reference...

    context<int> c; // ok
}
```

I'm not sure this counts as elegant though, as it gives you a two-step initialization process. This could be fixed by recognising the shared_instance itself as a kind of factory, making its contents non-static, and passing it into the contexts:

```
template< typename t >
struct context
{
    context(instance_provider< t >& provider): // now it can't be created unless this exists...
        instance{ provider.get_shared_instance() }
    { }

private:

    std::shared_ptr< t > instance;
};

int main()
{
    auto provider = instance_provider<int>([] () { return std::make_shared<int>(5); });

    context<int> c(provider);
}
```

### Further Considerations:

Does the C library you're using say anything about context lifetime itself? (e.g. Winsock reference counts calls to WSAStartup() and WSACleanup() internally, so as long as the calls are paired properly the C library handles cleaning up)

The main feature that this shared_instance class seems to provide is destroying The Instance promptly after the last context is destroyed. RAII itself could be achieved by just storing a unique pointer over the maximum possible lifetime of any contexts, which would be simpler. Is this prompt destruction actually important?

If not, then it's just a singleton, which we either live with, or do the work to pass a pointer or reference to the thing you need where it needs to be.

Comment: if i understood your second approach correctly, i could just create context<> c1{provider} and context<> c2{provider} which would both call the ctor of the context-type and the dtor of the context-type, so it might happen that objects have a context-member created from c1 while c2 already called the teardown-function, right?  passing in a lambda for lazy execution is a good idea when retreiving the parameters of the lambda is more expensive than the whole concept itself, setting the required params statically before calls to get_shared_instance() is propably cheapest (and the ugiest one) :)

Comment: i'm still marking your answer as accepted because of your efforts and additional input in further considerations. after all, my question was how to decorate an anti-pattern which can not be done much nicer than you suggested i suppse, thanks again for all your effort and considerations!